# How to remove the actual item in my ArrayList

Tags: vb.net

I have to work with an ArrayList and I have to remove the actual item and I don't know how to do, can you help me please? here's my code :

```
Public Sub Effacer_etu()
    Try
        _listeEtu.RemoveAt(NB_Etu - 1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

P.S. NB_Etu is the number of students in my ArrayList

Comment: Yes, that works.  If it doesn't work then you haven't found the real bug yet.  Like using NB_Etu instead of the Count property and it not actually being the number of items in the collection.  Which isn't unlikely because your removed an item but didn't change NB_Etu, that's not good of course.  Probably also inspired you to add Try/Catch, very bad idea.

Comment: How is it a bad idea to add a Try/Catch

Comment: Hard to guess what the problem is then.  Do you need ESP to guess what the "actual item" might be?  Don't guess, you need an index or an object reference to keep track of it.

Comment: If your removing the last element then why not - `_listeEtu.RemoveAt(_listeEtu.Count - 1)`

Comment: It's not always the last one that I want to remove OneFineDay, if I'm on the number 4, I want to delete this one, if I'm on the number 6 I want to delete this one....

Comment: If NB_Etu is the number of students in your list, then you are always removing the second last student? is that your intent?

Comment: @Vahx, if `BN_Etu` was the number of students then -1 is the last student in a zero based array. I think the OP is having a hard time explaining what they want.

Comment: @OneFineDay depends where he is getting his value for `BN_Etu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joël,

Your code uses a loop unnecessarily. You just need one line of code to remove the item. Try this:

```
Public Sub Effacer_etu()
    Try
        _listeEtu.Remove(_etudiant)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

You will get the same result without the unnecessary looping.

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved the problem, here's my Sub working

```
Public Sub Effacer_etu()
    Try
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To NB_Etu
            _listeEtu.Remove(_etudiant)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```