# Replace an item in an ArrayList (update an item in an List(Of T))

Tags: vb.net

I have wrote this code in Visual Studio and I want to replace 1 element in my ArrayList, however, when I click on the submit button, I can see the modifications and it also add 10 same elements, I don't know how to solve it, can you help me please?

```
Try
  Dim i As Integer
   For i = 0 To NB_Etu
       listeEtu.Insert(i, etuTmp)
   Next
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

NB_Etu is the number of students in my list (9)

Comment: If you want to replace a single element why are you using a `for` loop?

Comment: I looked at your previous question and posted an answer. You seem to be confused about what loops do. In your previous post a loop was completely unnecessary. In this question the loop to replace a single value makes no sense if it is not checking something with an `if` clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the actual item in my ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330930/how-to-remove-the-actual-item-in-my-arraylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, an `ArrayList` contains items, not elements.  It's a small thing but the term "element" is specifically for arrays.

Secondly, why are you using an `ArrayList` at all?  Since .NET 2.0, you really should be using a `List(Of T)` instead.

As for your question, if you want to replace an existing item then you should not be calling `Insert`.  `Insert` is like `Add` except that you can put the new item anywhere rather than just at the end.  To replace an existing item at a specific index, you need to set the `Item` property, just as you get the `Item` property to retrieve the item at a specific index.

Note that `Item` is the default property for `ArrayList` and `List(Of T)`, so you don't have to specify the property by name.  You can simply index the collection directly, just as you would an array.

Comment: My bad, it was not an ArrayList, but a List(Of T), I it wrote too quick

Comment: can you show me an example please? I will understand it with a visual code